# Bijective Linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an intuitive understanding that a linear map from two equal dimensional vector spaces that is injective is also surjective, because every element in the codomain is uniquely mapped to from the domain. Since the dimensions are the same, it's going to have to also be surjective. I'm not sure how to rigorously show this though?

Comment: Could you please check your question again?

Comment: "uniquely mapped to from the domain". This looks a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) explains with rigour your correct thought.